# No me coge el Código si lo pongo en el servicio.Angular5

Tags: angular

Tengo una aplicación de Angular5 donde estoy mostrando los meses siempre que el mes sea el actual o haya pasado, es decir, Ahora en Junio no mostrará Julio (por ejemplo.)

El problema es que he cogido el código, lo he movido a un servicio y ha dejado de funcionar.

Esto es lo que hago para cada mes del año

```
    <button clrTabLink id="february" 
  [disabled]="enableMonth(2)">Febrero</button>
    <clr-tab-content *clrIfActive>
    </clr-tab-content>
```

En el componente:

```
 public enableMonth(month: number){
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    if (month <= currentMonth) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Esto estaba funcionando hasta que lo cambié al servicio:

Component:

```
public enableMonth = function(month: number) {
    this.currentMonth = this.service.Mes(month);
```

}

Service:

```
 public Mes(month: number){
    console.log('entro'); 
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    if (month <= currentMonth) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Habiendo cambiado el código al servicio ahora muestra todos los meses del año.
y Saca muchos entro ... sólo hay 12 en este componente. Me está haciendo lo de los otros componentes ?

Comment: Faltan datos: ¿Cómo has modificado la plantilla? El método de tu componente ha modificado su comportamiento, antes devolvías algo y ahora lo guardas en un atributo.

Comment: Perfecto, entiendo lo que quieres decir, ya funciona, gracias!